# Разделить список значений на две части Python

Tags: python, list, tuple

Имеется список значений, представляющие собой расстояние до некоторой точки:

[1528,25, 1528,247, 1528,247, 1528,247, 1528,247, 1528,247, 1528,249, 1528,249, 1528,471, 1528,47]

Если построить по этому набору чисел диаграмму, то можно заметить резкий перепад значений (два последних значения намного больше всех остальных)

[image: Диаграмма]

Возможно ли средствами Python выделить из представленного списка два кортежа так, чтобы в первом из них были первые 8 значений, а во втором кортеже - остальные 2 значения? Возможно, средствами Python можно выделять подобные "выбросы"?

Comment: `lst[:8], lst[8:]` ?

Comment: Возможно! Причем на любом языке программирования!

Comment: Все очень сильно зависит от конкретного понимания задачи, в данном случае нельзя сказать однозначно, точнее решение есть но насколько оно будет эффективным зависит от конкретного применения, например при условии что чисел всего 8 можно попарно сравнивать числа и когда разница будет выше среднестатической ранее известной создать новую группу, но Вам нужно определится на какую разницу реагировать и насколько важна скорость работы (если список будет огромным)

Comment: найти выбросы - не проблема. вы должны для начала определить, насколько должна быть велика разница, чтобы считать значение выбросом. например, опираясь на среднее по выборке и стандартное отклонение.

Comment: Подскажите, какие библиотеки лучше использовать? Списки будут небольшие, максимум 20 значений в списке.